# Why is my SQL query with aggregate function returning the wrong values to me when running in larger query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a SQL query in order to calculate the monthly income and costs for some company. The values I am using to calculate the income is based on a table that lists the sales, while the costs are based on a table that lists all employees and their annual salaries. So, in order to calculate the monthly costs, I summed all the employees' annual salaries and divided them by 12. In order to calculate the monthly incomes, I grouped the sales by the month in which they were made and summed them up. The result would have three columns: the year/month, the monthly income, and the monthly cost.

However, there is something wrong with values in the monthly cost column. They all should be 8145, but instead, they are as follows:

```
year/month  monthly_income monthly_cost
2018-04     9300           2937
2018-03     3855           3000
2018-01     7875           2937
```

While the monthly income values are correct, the monthly cost values are incorrect. This result is based on the following SQL command:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(s.sale_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_month,
    (SUM(s.amount)) AS monthly_income,
    (SUM(e.annual_salary)/12) AS monthly_cost
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN sales s ON e.id = s.employee_id
GROUP BY year_month;
```

But what is more confusing is if I run this command but simplified to only calculating the sum of the employee's annual salaries divided by 12, I get the correct answer of 8145.

```
SELECT 
    (SUM(e.annual_salary)/12) AS monthly_cost
    from employees e;
```

So what is going on here? Any help would be appreciated. I have so far tried changing the formatting of the aggregate function, but to no avail.

Comment: Presumably, an employee can have more than 1 sale (would otherwise not be a very good salesperson). This means you get every salary multiple times, and sum all those times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(s.sale_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_month,
    (SUM(s.amount)) AS monthly_income,
    (select SUM(annual_salary) from employees)/12 AS monthly_cost
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN sales s ON e.id = s.employee_id
GROUP BY year_month;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! But I must ask, why did including this sub-query work where the original did not?

Comment: @BobMcBobson, You need the total of annual_salary for the whole table, not date_wise that's the reason it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Employees can have zero or more sales per months, so I wouldn't expect the numbers to add up.  Doing what you want is a bit complicated.  Getting the sales is simple:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(s.sale_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_month,
       SUM(s.amount) AS monthly_income
FROM employees e INNER JOIN
     sales s
     ON e.id = s.employee_id
GROUP BY year_month;
```

However, to get the salary of the employees is more complicated.  I think the best route is two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT year_month,
       SUM(employee_sales) AS monthly_income,
       SUM(annual_salary / 12) as salary
FROM (SELECT e.id, e.annual_salary, TO_CHAR(s.sale_date, 'YYYY-MM') as year_month, 
             SUM(s.amount) as employee_sales
      FROM employees e INNER JOIN
           sales s
           ON e.id = s.employee_id
      GROUP BY e.id, e.annual_salary, year_month
     ) es
GROUP BY year_month;
```